# Search URL to exclude certain results

Tags: url, search

I made a WordPress link to go to a page that shows only products on sale by using this URL.
https://mysite/shop/?product-status=on_sale&orderby=date So this is not an actual page.

It's just a link to filtered search results. The problem is this URL shows too many products under 'used' categories. I have a designated page for 'used' products only, so I don't need to show the used products on this page but still want to show recently added products so orderby=date is required.

The top tier category for used items is 'used' and there are many subcategories such as 'used audio', 'used video', etc. So I wonder if there's a way that I can exclude any products under categories with the names including 'used' **only modifying this search URL.**
Or if there's any smarter way to exclude 'used...' products on WordPress-WooCommerce filtered search result, I'll really appreciate it.

Bard gives me this URL to try, but didn't work.

/shop/?product-status=on-sale&orderby=date&exclude=used

And I tried this by searching some more, but didn't work either.
/shop/?product-status=on_sale&orderby=date#product_cat=used